# strange edge detection or something other?

Tags: vhdl

Here is code from Xilinx Zynq examples. I can't understand what is it for?

As I see *pulse_d2* is 1 only on the falling edge of *s_axi_resetn*.

What is a reason to detect falling edge in this way?

Why not to use events, something like "*if (s_axi_resetn'event and s_axi_resetn = '0')*" ?

```
process(s_axi_clk)
  begin
        if (s_axi_clk'event and s_axi_clk = '1') then
           if (s_axi_resetn = '0') then
               pulse <= '0';
           else
               pulse <= '1';
           end if;
        end if;
  end process;

  process(s_axi_clk)
  begin
        if (s_axi_clk'event and s_axi_clk = '1') then
           if (s_axi_resetn = '0') then
               pulse_d1 <= '0';
           else
               pulse_d1 <= pulse;
           end if;
        end if;
  end process;

  pulse_d2 <= pulse and (not pulse_d1);
```

Comment: Is this a Xilinx example? Imho they then made a some low quality code here. Weird signal naming. Not using `rising_edge`. And everything could be written so much more efficiently.

Comment: Yes, this code is from AXI Datamover example. Could you please give some more efficient code or other variant with the same functionality for the purpose of learning ?

Answer (score 1):

On rising edges of `s_axi_clk` for which `s_axi_resetn` is low, `pulse` and `pulse_d1` are forced to `'0'` and `pulse_d2` also takes value '`0`'.

On the first rising edge of `s_axi_clk` for which `s_axi_resetn` is high, `pulse` goes high but `pulse_d1` samples the current value of `pulse`, that is, `'0'`. `pulse_d2` thus takes value '`1`'.

On the second rising edge of `s_axi_clk` for which `s_axi_resetn` is high, `pulse` stays high and `pulse_d1` goes high. `pulse_d2` thus takes value '`0`'.

On the following rising edges of `s_axi_clk` for which `s_axi_resetn` is high, `pulse` and `pulse_d1` stay high. `pulse_d2` thus takes value '`0`'.

So, this design is a way to detect the de-assertion of the reset and to signal it with a single clock period pulse high on `pulse_d2`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have cited is an example of a *synchronous edge detector* - see, for example, [this on my company's website](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/synchronisation/).

This is used to detect an edge on some signal which is not the clock and hence is *synchronous design*.

> For a design to be synchronous
>
> 1. all the flip flops should be clocked all the time from the same edge
>      of the same clock
> 2. there should be no latches
> 3. there should be no *combinational feedback*.

If you implemented your edge detector using the code

```
if (s_axi_resetn'event and s_axi_resetn = '0')
```

then this would synthesise to a flip flop which is clocked by the signal `s_axi_resetn`. You have just broken rule #1 and your design is no longer synchronous.

For various reasons, a real design is unlikely to be fully synchronous. However, you should minimse the number of departures from synchronous design and any departure should literally keep you awake at night. Hence, you should always use a synchronous edge detector to detect an edge on a signal instead of connecting that signal to the clock input of a flip flop.

Comment: Thanks, very useful! I suppose such edge detector could be made as a component design.